# Cannot run logstash with Spring Boot 3.0 due to namespace conflict with "jakarta"/"javax"

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback

We are in the process of upgrading to **Spring Boot 3.x** and at runtime we are running into this exception : **"class not found exception" for : javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule.setupModule(JaxbAnnotationModule.java:98)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:879)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:1081)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1165)
    at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.createJsonFactory(AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.java:247)
    at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.start(AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.java:117)
    at net.logstash.logback.LogstashFormatter.start(LogstashFormatter.java:144)
    at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.start(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:129)
```

On closer inspection this seems to be caused by **logstash** , a logging framework used with elastic search.

The current version of logstash was **6.4.x**, so we bumped it up to **7.4.x** (using Gradle: implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")), but we still got the same problem.

The reason is that there is a dependency indirectly using xml bindings (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder/7.4) The problem is that there is a dependency on logback (called **logback-classic**) that uses XML bindings. Upon researching a bit and coming across this website : https://logback.qos.ch/news.html, we realised that there are two versions of logback classic that use different namespaces.

```
logback-classic 1.3.x -> uses javax namespace 
logback-classic 1.4.x -> uses jakarta namespace
```

My understanding is we would need to update logback-classic to 1.4 because that version uses the jakarta namespace which is compatible with the SpringBoot 3.x xml bindings.

So we explicitly set the logback-classic to 1.4 in the gradle build like so :

```
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.14")
implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")
```

However now when we run it we get a different error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader.systemClassloaderIfNull(java.lang.ClassLoader)'
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:73)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:66)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:52)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
```

Comment: Looks like you use incompatible versions of `lockback-classic` and `logback-core`

Comment: @Oliver Watkins: any Solution found? I am stuck with the same problem, finding it weird, that there are so few people with it

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that there is a version discrepancy. I found this in official documentation of logstash-logback-encoder README.

https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder

```
If you get ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError/NoSuchMethodError at runtime, then ensure the required dependencies (and appropriate versions) as specified in the pom file from the maven repository exist on the runtime classpath. Specifically, the following need to be available on the runtime classpath:

jackson-databind / jackson-core / jackson-annotations >= 2.12.0
logback-core >= 1.3.0
logback-classic >= 1.3.0 (required for logging LoggingEvents)
logback-access >= 1.3.0 (required for logging AccessEvents)
slf4j-api (usually comes as a transitive dependency of logback-classic)
java-uuid-generator (required if the uuid provider is used)
```

Comment: did you use maven or gradle? I followed these steps but I used a runtimOnly configuration for these versions in my gradle file, and it still doesn't work

Comment: I am even at 1.4.11. But those libraries still use the javax.xml.bind imports, which fail. And the dependency comes directly from spring boot starter itself